# Update Table using SQL Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update fields in a table using a cursor but the update is not happening and I do not know why.  Here is my SQL query:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeCompanyId int

SELECT DISTINCT  EmployeeCompanyId
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Company_Employee_Contacts]


OPEN MY_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @EmployeeCompanyId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_Company_Employee_Contacts]
    SET City = (SELECT TOP 1 Phone 
                FROM [dbo].[tbl_Company_Employee_Contacts]
                WHERE EmployeeCompanyId = @EmployeeCompanyId 
                 AND City IS NOT NULL)
    WHERE EmployeeCompanyId = @EmployeeCompanyId 
       AND City IS NOT NULL

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @EmployeeCompanyId
END

CLOSE MY_CURSOR
```

Table was created with a single piece of contact information per record.  I am trying to consolidate all info into one record so that I can delete the others:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use a `CURSOR` at all? SQL is a set based language, you should be using set based solutions. What are you *actually" trying to achieve here? Sample data and expected breaults will help us help you.

Comment: `SET City = (SELECT TOP 1 Phone...`?

Comment: Why do you think you need a cursor for this, it's a simple update - although somewhat confusing to be setting a `city` to a `phone number`, I would worry about your data quality lol.

Comment: @Stu the phone/city was a typo.

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I would probably just aggregate all the columns using `max()` and group on the `EmployeeCompanyId` then correlate back on the max `id` and update, depending on the rules you have for choosing the `type` and `subtype`

Comment: @Stu - we are trying to get rid of type and subtype all together.  I just want to put all of the contact info we have for each employee into one record.  I don't understand what you mean regarding "correlate back on the max id and update".

Comment: @RaniRadcliff I've posted an example of what I mean below to aggregate and update all rows in a set-based fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other people have stated in the comments, I don't know why the `CURSOR` is even necessary here.  But the problem with your code above is that you didn't `DECLARE` the `CURSOR` first in your initial `SELECT`.

```
DECLARE @EmployeeCompanyId int

DECLARE MY_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT  EmployeeCompanyId
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_Company_Employee_Contacts]


OPEN MY_CURSOR

FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @EmployeeCompanyId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    UPDATE [dbo].[tbl_Company_Employee_Contacts]
    SET City = (SELECT TOP 1 Phone 
                FROM [dbo].[tbl_Company_Employee_Contacts]
                WHERE EmployeeCompanyId = @EmployeeCompanyId 
                 AND City IS NOT NULL)
    WHERE EmployeeCompanyId = @EmployeeCompanyId 
       AND City IS NOT NULL

    FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @EmployeeCompanyId
END

CLOSE MY_CURSOR
```

Comment: There are over 200,000 records in the table and over 65,000 distinct IDs.  I could not think of any other way to accomplish what was needed besides iterating through the values.  Thank you for your response.  I had figured out that I had missed that step and had logged back on to say that in case it helped anyone else when I saw your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Something you could do is the following. you haven't provided any concrete sample data and desired results so this is just a mock-up but should give you something to work with, and no `cursor` in sight.

```
/* sample data */
create table T (id int, EmployeeCompanyId int, Phone varchar(20), Street varchar(50))
insert into T values
(1,     10,'1234567890', null),
(1202,  10,'1234567890', null),
(78086, 10, null, 'Larose'),
(144887,10, null, 'Larose')

select * from T;

/* Update the highest ID row for each employee with data for each column*/
with u as (
    select Max(Id) Id, Max(Phone) Phone, Max(Street) Street
    from T
    group by EmployeeCompanyId
)
update t set
    t.phone=u.phone,
    t.street=u.street
from u
join T  on t.Id=u.Id

select * from T

/* delete all redundant rows for each employee */
/* This keeps the highest ID, if you want to put all data on the lowest ID, reverse the criteria accordingly */


with u as (
select EmployeeCompanyId, id, Row_Number() over (partition by EmployeeCompanyId order by id desc) rn
from t
)
delete from t
from u join t on t.Id=u.Id
where u.rn>1

select * from T
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not sure why this is better than the cursor, but I will try it.  Should this be faster than the cursor?

Comment: Faster - well try it and see. If it's not an order of magnitude faster I'll eat my hat. (I have a chocolate hat). Post back with your results.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, the above does exactly what your loop does, except it does it for all columns and for all employees, not one at a time. You can refine it and test just the query in the CTE `with u as` to pick the right data for each column. `max` on a column will give you the same as `select top 1 ... where value is not null` assuming the rows with non-null values are the same (like in your example) and if you had 2 rows for an employee with different phone numbers it will pick the max alphabetically (just like your `select top 1` picks one at random with no `order by`

Comment: @RaniRadcliff in 99.9% of situations a *set-based* solution will be *better* (in every meaning of the word, faster, use less resources, cause less locking) than a RBAR (Row By Agonising Row) solution. Because relational databases are designed and optimised for set-based operations. So you should always be trying to find a set-based solution. The an example of an exception would be needing to call a stored procedure once per id or similar. But for straight updates, and selects you should always be able to find a set based solution.